# Kotlin: Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch: inferred type is Pair<String, Int> but Pair<Product, Int> was expected

Tags: kotlin

I wanna call run the following function addToCart() in the main, but such error appears, may i know how should i change my code?
Thanks!

```
    fun addToCart(){
    println("Productname : ")
    var nameInput= readLine() ?: "-"
    println("Num of $nameInput ")
    var num = readLine()!!.toInt()
    var got : Product? = warehouse.getProductByName(nameInput)
    shoppingCart.addToList(nameInput, num)

}
```

---

```
class ShoppingCart () {
            private val productAndQuantityList = mutableListOf<Pair<Product, Int>>()
            fun addToList(name: String, quantity: Int){
                productAndQuantityList.add(Pair(name, quantity))
            }
        ....
        }
```

Comment: You seem to have defined your own Pair class

Comment: Thanks for replying! should i delete or add any codes? let me know if more info is needed.

Comment: Remove your Pair class and just use the one Kotlin gives you, I guess. It'll make life a lot easier

Comment: Would you give me the error message?

Comment: i changed the last line to "shoppingCart.productAndQuantityList.add(Pair(first = got, second = num) )" but same error appears. may i know how should i change the code? Thanks!

Comment: I think I can tell how to change your code, but I would like to ask what is the error message you got from IntelliJ? I tried your code in IntelliJ but I did not get an error.  I suppose, that I miss some information.

Comment: @user i didn't know i have defined my own Pair class, may i know what is the correct code? if i delete "Pair" and write it as // shoppingCart.productAndQuantityList.add(Pair(first = got, second = num) , there are other errors. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @jseteny thanks for your kindness. Error message is "Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is kotlin.Pair<Product, Int> but Pair<Product, Int> was expected"

Comment: Yeah, that error suggests that you have 2 `Pair` classes. Can you show the rest of your code?

Comment: @user updated, you are right! I didn't notice it. Thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need not null checks before calling add.

```
fun addProductToCart(shoppingCart: ShoppingCart, warehouse: Warehouse) {
    println("Product name: ")
    var productName_E = readLine() ?: "-"
    println("No. of $productName_E ")
    var num = readLine()?.toInt()
    var got: Product? = warehouse.getProductByName(productName_E)
    if (num != null && got != null) {
        shoppingCart.productAndQuantityList.add(Pair(first = got, second = num))
    }
}
```

Your ShoppingCart class should be something like the class below.

```
class ShoppingCart {

    val productAndQuantityList = mutableListOf<kotlin.Pair<Product, Int>>()
    ...
}
```

Comment: @user12595983 Using kotlin.Pair explicitly in the val productAndQuantityList = mutableListOf<kotlin.Pair<Product, Int>>() line should solve the problem.

Comment: @jseteny not yet fixed, but my class is similar to your guess. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: @user12595983 This is just a workaround though - you likely have a bigger problem where you've imported 2 copies of Pair